# exim4 with different configtype

Tags: exim

My goal is the following situation on my computer (ComputerA):

- send emails (generated by cron) to another local mail server (ComputerB)
- send emails (generated by a particular task) to gmail

Currently, the first part is working correctly. Here is the config files:

### ComputerA

**/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf**

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='satellite'
dc_other_hostnames='tsl.local'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1;::1;'
dc_readhost='tsl.local'
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='mail.tsl.local'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

**/etc/aliases**

```
root: mailuser
```

### ComputerB

**/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf**

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
...
```

**/etc/aliases**

```
mailuser: email@something.com
```

---

On **ComputerA**, when I run

```
echo 'World'| mail -s 'Hello' root
```

it is working correctly. In my understanding, this email is routed by **ComputerB**, and then to Internet.

Now I would like to be able to do the following:

```
echo 'World'| mail -s 'Hello' bob
```

And this email should be sent to a gmail address (**without** being routed to **ComputerB**).

So I edit **/etc/aliases**:

```
root: mailuser
bob: bob@gmail.com
```

But then I'm not sure how to configure exim4 for a different configtype (**satellite** and **internet**).

I found example how to setup exim4 for gmail only, but not for a 'mix'.

Should I create a manual route in **/etc/exim4/conf.d/router** and stop using **update-exim4.conf.conf**?